# ListPicker selection changed issue in Windows Phone

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, listpicker

I have binded listpicker in OnNavigatedTo event,
and I have an event of "listPickerSelectionChanged", but problem is that even I have not selected the item from listPicker, the "listPickerSelectionChanged" event called and error occurs, how to prevent it?

Comment: could you please share your listPickerSelectionChanged event code. it gives more idea, whats the best solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have set the **SelectedIndex value to 0** it triggers the Selection changed event even before the Databinding, So as no data is avilable at the 0th index it throws error

**If set to 0 change it to -1** ,

If not please specify the error being thrown

Comment: selectedindex is already set to -1,give me another solution..thanks!!

Comment: error is that "Object Reference not set to an instance of Object"

Answer (score 0):

"Object Reference not set to an instance of Object" , Some value it captured null at the time of execution, without code reference can't get into any solution
Debugging may help you out.